# Angular event listeners as attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive

I have several directives over input fields that emit semantic events such as `edit-end` `edit-cancel`. Is there a way to specify what to do with them using attributes on parent element, rather than create a controller? Something like

```
<div on-edit-end="editEnded()" on-edit-cancel="editCanceled()">
  <input edit-directive ng-model="foo"/>
  <input edit-directive ng-model="bar"/>
</div>
```

(Where `editEnded` and `editCancelled` are defined on the root scope)
I know I can create a separate directive called `on-event` or something similar, to catch events, but am looking for something standard.

Comment: So your real issue is wanting `editEnded` and `editCanceled` to be methods on `$rootScope` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have parent `directive` with some name something as `outerDir` over all the inputs fields, which would have own controller with having `editEnded` & `editCanceled` method exposed. By that the inner directive could get access to those method by mentioning parent directive name inside `require` option prefix with `^`(indicated parent) like `require: '^outerDir'`

**Markup**

```
<div outer-dir on-edit-end="editEnded()" on-edit-cancel="editCanceled()">
  <input edit-directive ng-model="foo"/>
  <input edit-directive ng-model="bar"/>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('outerDir', function(){
   return { 
      scope: {
          onEditEnd: '&',
          onEditCancel: '&'
      },
      link: function(scope, attr){
      },
      controller: function(scope){
          scope.editEndedEvent = scope.onEditEnd;
          scope.editCancelledEvent = scope.onEditCancel;
      }
   }
})


app.directive('editDirective', function(){
   return { 
      require: '^outerDir', //this line will get controller of `outerDir` directive
      link: function(scope, attr, outerDirController){ //controller is available in 4th parameter
          //on edit call parent directive controller method
          scope.onEdit = function(){
             outerDirController.editEndedEvent(); // call edit
          }
          scope.onCancel = function(){
             outerDirController.editCancelledEvent(); // call cancel
          }
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: well, I didn't want to create a controller. a directive is just another way of creating a controller.

Comment: @IttayD I think it would be correct way to deal with `directive to directive` communication.. don't think like creating directive with controller as an overhead as it can have `sharable` methods to share those with its underlying directives..

Answer (score 1):

Directives can create their own scope and as such don't need a controller as a parent. Just simply define the scope property on your directive to an empty object and it will work just fine. [See this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tt7Zn8xr5BZZ3jK4y3Mt).

```
angular.module('app', [])
.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.added = true;
}])
.directive('thing', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      element.attr('added', $rootScope.added);
      console.log($rootScope);
    },
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {}
  }
}]);
```